# Multiple tokens (for multiple services) for single user in mobile application

Tags: database, oauth, jwt, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making a hybrid mobile application, using Ionic and Cordova, for which I would like to give the user the possibility to sign up/log in with Facebook, G+, Linkedin and Instagram, and email account. I would indentify everyone by their email (to check if it's the same person, it is not a pk in the database but just an index).

I have been looking around for information about OAuth2 and looking into the documentation for the services APIs. I have understood what I have to do in the front, but I have some questions on the whole process:

1. [BACK] How do I check the tokens provided by the services APIs? Let's say when a user logs in with Facebook, I get a token which is stored in the user's phone. Then, on every HTTP request, I have to attach the JWT to verify the user indentity. How do I verify it? Against what do I have to test it?
2. I want to be able to get information from the user's G+ account but also the user's Linkedin account (example). How do I manage this properly?
   Do I just store both (or more) tokens (in local storage) and use them to authenticate? I want to do this as my app will have "friends lists", so the user will be able to log into external services and the app will get the user's friends/contact list from those apps.

As of now, I think about including an `auth_method` field in my database to store available authentication methods (a JSON string or something like that), and just add four fields (one for each service) `default null` where I would store the token created for the user.

I can show you my code but it do not think it would help as these are more of theory and not specific to a language.

Thank you for all the help!